# Laravel and oauth 2

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel, oauth-2.0

I have searched high and low but haven't come across anything that can help.

I'm very new to oAuth.

I am using https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel.

I am building a REST API service. `The Client` will be the Website. I am using the `Password Flow` to authenticate.

My understanding, please correct me if I am wrong.

`oauth_clients` table (id,secret,name). `The Client` is the Website not the individual users who logs on to the website. I will be using `The Client`'s id and secret with the individual user's username and password.

I am following the instructions on the page above.

I am using the `POST` method on `http://api.domain.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=password&client_id=BCA545A934F5F4528DA3EE567E8E4&client_secret=5184B7C4E11ED3EEF99DA1A1DD9C3&username=email@email.com&password=password&scope=scope1,scope2&state=123456789`

This authenticates both the client and user fine but here is the issue. I have no idea where I set the `scope` or the `state`

This is the Response `{
  "error": "invalid_scope",
  "error_description": "The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed. Check the \"scope1\" scope."
}`

I honestly don't know what the next step is even if I set the Scope or the State what is the next step?

Thanks.

## EDIT

I added a dummy record to the scope table and added that value to the to scope and it worked.

I do understand scope now, I just don't know why it's required.

I received a Response with the Access Token. I actually understand the concept of oAuth now. I've already implemented a log in/access token system but I might get rid of that and stick with oAuth.
I was trying to use oAuth to authenticate the website to the REST API Service but it doesn't look like that's the way to do it.

So now my next question is: Is there a way to add the access token to the Header instead as a URL parameter?

Comment: Are you trying to make a oauth service or trying to login user with social auth service ?

Comment: oAuth Service. Is there a better way to connect an API service to a Website. I would like to lock the API down so only the website can access it with the potential of opening up parts of the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publish the OAuth2 server [configuration](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel#configuration) (if not already done)  using

```
php artisan config:publish lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel
```

Open the file `app/config/packages/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/oauth2.php`

If you don't need scopes, just add a single scope named `basic` to `oauth_scopes`  table.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Scope
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The default scope to use if not present in the query string
    |
    */
    'default_scope' => 'basic',
```

No need to add scope parameter in access_token request now.

> Q2:Is there a way to add the access token to the Header instead as a
>   URL parameter?

Yes.By default it checks both the query string and the http headers.

Change the below option to `true`  to prevent access_token validation when provided as a query string

```
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Header Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This will tell the resource server where to check for the access_token.
    | By default it checks both the query string and the http headers
    |
    */
    'http_headers_only' => false,
```