# The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed in file vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Exception\OAuthServerException.php on line 182

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-passport

I have update `composer.json` file from

```
"require": {
   "php": "^7.3|^8.0"
}
```

to

```
"require": {
   "php": "^7.4|^8.0"
}
```

and run composer update now getting error  The requested scope is invalid, unknown, or malformed in file `vendor\league\oauth2-server\src\Exception\OAuthServerException.php` on line 182

I revert everything by deleting vendor folder `composer.json.lock` file and use the old lock file and install packages again but issue still persists.

I'm using passport and error came on $user->createToken('Customer Access Token', ['user']);

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883481/laravel-and-oauth-2 don't let the fact that this only showed up now with a simple composer.json change. It's likely the command was broken for a while now you just never happened to need to run it since it broke

Comment: If such an error is thrown, that is usually not a problem of Composer, nor any problem related to [tag:rest]

Comment: @apokryfos I try the solution you have shared and got this  
 Command "config:publish" is not defined.

Comment: @NicoHaase I know this is related to package compatibility but don't know how to fix this, possible solutions that I have tired I shared in details.

Comment: If you already know that this is **not** a problem with [tag:rest] or [tag:composer-php], please remove these tags. Also, if rolling back the package installation to the previous version did not resolve the problem, please rephrase the whole question to contain more details about the **previous** setup (like which package version you've used)

Comment: I think it's called `vendor:publish` in newer Laravel versions

Comment: After debugging found the solution, laravel route we caches and in passport we have condition in AuthServiceProvider.php boot method
 if(!$this->app->routesAreCached()) so route cache clear solve issue for me